# Java Base64 encoding loss of data

Tags: java, base64, byte, encode, binary-data

say I have the following snippet, where `certificate` is a java Certificate object:

```
byte[] data = certificate.getEncoded();

String stringData = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(data));

byte[] newData = Base64.decodeBase64(stringData)
```

Is there any chance `data` will not be equal to `newData`? basically, is there loss of information to string and then back?
Thanks

Comment: No. Each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of data. Three bytes (24 bits) are represented by four 6-bit Base64 digits. The result is 33% larger, but 100% isomorphic to the input.

Comment: Should you choose right CharacterSet when you convert byte[] to String?

Comment: As Joachim points out in a comment below, using Base64.getEncoder().[encodeToString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString(byte%5B%5D))(data) would both solve the problem and remove your dependency on an external library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming nothing explodes due to out-of-memory errors or similar general problems, this code should be fine, with one big exception:

You are transforming the output of `Base64.encodeBase64` (which is a `byte[]`) to a `String` without specifying the encoding.

This is generally speaking a bad idea, because it will use the platform default encoding.

In this specific case, it's unlikely to be an actual problem. Because the output of Base64 contains only ASCII characters and  almost all modern platforms use a ASCII-compatible encoding as their platform default encoding (for example Android, Mac OS X and most Linux distributions use UTF-8, Windows tends to use some code-page, but the lower 128 bytes are usually also ASCII compatible).

Still, it would be better to use `new String(Base64.encodeBase64(data), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)` just to be sure (for the reasons mentioned above, `ISO_8859_1` and `UTF_8` would work as well, but `US_ASCII` is the "correct" pick).

Comment: Agreed, mentioning the encoding is important.

Comment: Docs say [UTF-8](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64-byte:A-) is correct *Returns:
`byte[]` containing Base64 characters in their UTF-8 representation.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: that's technically true, but I don't see how this can have any effect unless one passes in a non-ASCII line seperator to the constructor, which OP isn't even using.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It should be 7-bit safe output, so UTF-8 and US-ASCII should be effectively identical; but the docs do say UTF-8 (not sure why). Also, I'd prefer [`Base64.Encoder.encodeToString(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) in my own code.